# Font size doesn't match the size specified in the code when sending email with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, html-email, office-automation

This is the code:

```
Sub SendEmail(Body as String, EmailTo as String, EmailCC as String, EmailSubject as String, Message as String, Title as String)
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem

Body = "<font face=""Calibri""; size= ""11pt""; color:""#000000"">" & Message & "</font>"
Signature = "<font face=""Arial""; size=""11pt""; color=""#808080"">Kind regards<br><br></font>" & _
            "<font face=""Arial""; size=""10pt""; color=""#808080"">" & Title & "</font>"

Set Email = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Email.To = EmailTo
Email.CC = EmailCC
Email.Subject = EmailSubject
Email.HTMLBody = Body & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Signature
Email.Send
End Sub
```

In the email sent, the colors and fonts are correct but the font sizes are 36, not 11 and 10 as I want them to be. Anyone knows why this might be?

Comment: The `"pt"` suffix is valid in CSS but not vanilla HTML. The `font` element's `size` attribute can be `"1"` to `"7"` and nothing else. Consider using CSS?.

Comment: Thank you! I googled and tried this ```<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11'>``` but the font size turned out to be 8pt in the email. How do I use CSS?

Comment: This is weird. ```<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:15pt'>``` turns out to be 11pt in the sent email. Why is that? Is it safe to use ```15pt``` and expect 11pt? Or is it different results depending on what email client you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can designate the text size on your web page using the 'size' attribute in the HTML font element code. If no size is defined for text on a web page then the web browser will display the text at size 3.

The value that you enter for the size attribute is a number representing any one of seven different relative sizes. These number 1 through 7 respectively.

Another way of designating your text size is to enter a number from 1 through 4 which either adds or subtracts from your `basefont` size. In the absence of a `basefont` declaration, the default `basefont` is size 3. By entering a value of "+1" for the size attribute you designate your text to be displayed one size bigger which then equates to size 4. Likewise a value of "+2" equates to font size 5. Going in the other direction, a value of "-1" equates to size 2 and "-2" equates to size 1 (`basefont` size 3 - 2 = font size 1).

If you need to use `px` or `pt` in the markup you can try using [CSS Font Size](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font_size.asp) instead.